# WPF: NavigationService is NULL after 2nd page visit

Tags: wpf, navigation

Scenario:

I have a NavigationWindow style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="NavigationWindow" x:Key="{x:Type NavigationWindow}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="NavigationWindow" >
                    ...
</Style>
```

I start my app with loading a Page called Home.xaml.
In Home.xaml I have a button that navigates to another page called PersonalData:

```
private void btnNewUser_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PersonalData personalData = new PersonalData();
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(personalData);
}
```

This works fine and the PersonalData Page gets loaded.
On that second Page I have a button "Home" that navigates back to the Home page:

```
    private void btnHome_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Home home = new Home();
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(home);
    }
```

I use "Navigate" here because I want to reuse that button on later forms too, to always have a button that leads to the start page.

So this also works and the Home page gets loaded. I can even click btnNewUser there a second time and again, the PersonalData page gets opened without any problems.

BUT, when I then click the "Home" button for the second time, I get an error that "this.NavigationService" is null..

I've just started with WPF and I have no idea where to start on fixing this.. Anyone?

Answer (score -1):

Try **KeepAlive=True** on your **Page** (for those which are gonna use the NavigationService).

The reason this problem happens is that NavigationService is being freed after you navigate to other pages in order to save more memory.

[Reference - Page Lifetime and the Journal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx)